# Single-disk array full: how to add a spare disk without losing data?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, hard-drive, software-raid, nvme

So I rent this server from Hetzner and it was labeled as 2x512gb nvme ssd. Indeed, the server contains two 512 gb nvme ssd but (my fault) I noticed only later that they were in some sort of software RAID.

I managed to remove a disk from the array and format it, so now /proc/mdstat reports:

```
md2 : active raid1 nvme1n1p3[1]
  465894720 blocks super 1.2 [1/1] [U]
  bitmap: 1/4 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk
```

and df -h reports

```
/dev/nvme0n1p3  437G   73M  415G   1% /media/disk2
```

I'd like to expand nvme1n1p3 with nvme0n1p3  so i get the space in a single partition, but I cant loose the data on the mounted raid which is almost full. Is there a way to do that?

Ideally, I would simply destroy the RAID thing and go on with a normal LVM but i don't know how to do it without loosing all the data.

Comment: There's nothing on that drive anyway, so there's nothing to lose.

Comment: why not mount the second drive on a specific path and use it as additional space?

Comment: can you add the full display of `df -h`